# DDD: Which layer to generate notification message in?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Let's say I have a system where a user gets sent a notification when someone invites them to a meeting. In this case, I want to send out a push notification displaying the message 'Someone just invited you to a meeting!' along with some metadata like the meeting ID.

I think most of us can agree that the logic for dispatching this notification should be executed within the application service layer (as opposed to a domain service, or the domain itself).

But my question is, which layer dictates the actual message that is sent?

Let's say that after executing its business logic, the domain layer emits an 'UserInvited' event with a corresponding 'MeetingID'.

The application layer then catches the event before synchronously calling a notification interface. At what point should the display message 'Someone just invited you to a meeting!' be added?

Option 1:

The message is generated within the domain and attached to the event. This seems not quite right though because the domain should not know or care about UI. Notifications have nothing to do with business logic.

Option 2:

The message is generated in the service layer. The domain entity returns a 'UserInvited' event which the service layer then translates into a Message object, which is in-turn passed to the notification interface. Messages are hardcoded with various different types of messages depending on the event type. For example 'UserUninvited' would have a 'You've been uninvited' message, etc.

This seems like the easiest way to do it, but also seems like a hack. The service layer should just provide an execution environment for the domain, nothing more. It shouldn't have logic in it about UI, etc.

Option 3:

Hardcode messages in the implementation of the notification interface itself. The service layer would just pass raw domain events through the notification interface and it would be the notification interface's responsibility to generate the appropriate messages depending on the event type.

This doesn't seem ideal because the notification service is just an infrastructure abstraction. It shouldn't care about what message is sent, only how to send it.

Am I missing further options? Any insight as far as where to generate and attach a notification message?

Comment: "Notifications have nothing to do with business logic." Is this true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#2 seems like the right place to make the decision to send a notification. But it doesn't mean it has to decide on the actual contents and specifics of the message.

You can delegate that to the adapter that talks to the notification library. The adapter is a bridge between your world and the world of whatever notification technology. It can still have methods that use the ubiquitous language of your application, such as `SendInvitationNotification()`, `SendRejectionNotification()` and so on, much in the same way that Repositories or Read Model facades can expose `GetInvitedUsers()` or `GetTodaysMeetings()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still don't think this is necessarily 100% ideologically pure DDD (after all, any message that reaches an end user is still UI imo), but it is probably the best and only choice possible.

Comment: DDD as an approach never had strong opinions about the Infrastructure / UI outskirts of an application. Here I'm talking about an adapter whose interface is in the Domain layer and implementation resides in Infrastructure. But you can perfectly put (part of) the impl in the UI corner of Infrastructure if you want.